# ansible comparing all files in 2 directories and printing the difference

Tags: diff, ansible, file-comparison

I have 2 directories

```
$ tree dir{1..2}
dir1
├── file1
└── file2
dir2
├── file1
└── file2
```

I want to compare all files in dir1 with all files in dir2 using ansible
and print differences like this

```
output:
${file1} from ${dir1}:
diff content

${file1} from ${dir2}:
diff content
```

and it will loop through all files to print their differences

below is ansible snippet that needs modification

```
---
- name: Compare files in two directories
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Find files in directory 1
      find:
        paths: ~/dir1
        file_type: file
      register: dir1_files

    - name: Find files in directory 2
      find:
        paths: ~/dir2
        file_type: file
      register: dir2_files

    - name: Compare files
      shell: diff dir1/file1 dir2/file1 ## how can I make sure path changes but filenames stay same using variables
      loop: "{{ dir1_files.files }}"
      register: diff_output
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: diff_output.rc == 1

    - name: Print differences
      debug:
        msg: |
          {{ item.item.path }} from dir1:
          {{ item.stdout }}
          {{ item.item.path }} from dir2:
          {{ item.stdout }}
      loop: "{{ diff_output.results }}"
      when: item.stdout_lines | length > 0
```

For suggested code in Vladimir's answer, I get below output

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "file2 from dir1: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < abc123\n  < def456\n  ---\n  > abc101\n  > def111\nfile2 from dir2: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < abc123\n  < def456\n  ---\n  > abc101\n  > def111\nfile1 from dir1: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < 123abc\n  < 456def\n  ---\n  > 101abc\n  > 111def\nfile1 from dir2: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < 123abc\n  < 456def\n  ---\n  > 101abc\n  > 111def\n"
}
```

Comment: In the Jinja2 template (*`msg`*), both *`{{ item.stdout }}`* are the same. Right? [edit] the question and provide [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the example of expected output.

Comment: If any of the files differ the *shell* task will fail because of the condition *`failed_when: diff_output.rc == 1`*. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, given the files

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls -1 /tmp/dir[1,2]
/tmp/dir1:
file1
file2

/tmp/dir2:
file1
file2
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 ls -1 /tmp/dir[1,2]
/tmp/dir1:

/tmp/dir2:
```

and the differences

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 diff /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/dir2/file1
31,32d30
< User1:*:1002:1004:My User1:/home/User1:/bin/sh
< MyUser1:*:1003:1005:My User1:/home/MyUser1:/bin/sh
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 diff /tmp/dir1/file2 /tmp/dir2/file2
33,34d32
< alice:*:1004:1006:Alice:/home/alice:/bin/sh
< bob:*:1005:1007:Bob:/home/bob:/bin/sh
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  dir1: /tmp/dir1
  dir2: /tmp/dir2
  dir1_files: "{{ out_dir1.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
  dir2_files: "{{ out_dir2.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
```

and find the files

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: "{{ dir1 }}"
        file_type: file
      register: out_dir1
    - find:
        paths: "{{ dir2 }}"
        file_type: file
      register: out_dir2
```

Find the shared files. Declare the variable

```yaml
  files_common: "{{ dir1_files|map('basename')|
                    intersect(dir2_files|map('basename')) }}"
```

gives (abridged) for test_11 and test_13 respectively

```yaml
  files_common:
  - file1
  - file2

  files_common: []
```

Compare the shared files. You have to ignore the errors because *diff* returns *rc=1* if the files differ

```yaml
  - command: "diff {{ dir1 }}/{{ item }} {{ dir2 }}/{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ files_common }}"
    ignore_errors: true
    register: out_diff
```

and create the report

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in out_diff.results %}
          {{ i.cmd|join(' ') }}: |
            {{ i.stdout|indent(2) }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives (abridged) for test_11 and test_13 respectively

```yaml
  msg: |-
    diff /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/dir2/file1: |
      31,32d30
      < User1:*:1002:1004:My User1:/home/User1:/bin/sh
      < MyUser1:*:1003:1005:My User1:/home/MyUser1:/bin/sh
    diff /tmp/dir1/file2 /tmp/dir2/file2: |
      33,34d32
      < alice:*:1004:1006:Alice:/home/alice:/bin/sh
      < bob:*:1005:1007:Bob:/home/bob:/bin/sh

  msg: ""
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    dir1: /tmp/dir1
    dir2: /tmp/dir2
    dir1_files: "{{ out_dir1.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
    dir2_files: "{{ out_dir2.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
    files_common: "{{ dir1_files|map('basename')|
                      intersect(dir2_files|map('basename')) }}"
    
    
  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: "{{ dir1 }}"
        file_type: file
      register: out_dir1
    - find:
        paths: "{{ dir2 }}"
        file_type: file
      register: out_dir2
    - debug:
        var: files_common

    - command: "diff {{ dir1 }}/{{ item }} {{ dir2 }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files_common }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: out_diff
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in out_diff.results %}
          {{ i.cmd|join(' ') }}: |
            {{ i.stdout|indent(2) }}
          {% endfor %}
```

---

**Q: *"The msg module output is not to my liking I would rather prefer a format similar to that given in Q inside the output section can it be achieved?"***

A: Sure. Try the template below. If this is not what you like edit your question and provide an example of what you like better

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in out_diff.results %}
          {{ i.cmd.1|basename }} from {{ i.cmd.1|dirname }}: 
            {{ i.stdout|indent(2) }}
          {{ i.cmd.2|basename }} from {{ i.cmd.2|dirname }}: 
            {{ i.stdout|indent(2) }}
          {% endfor %}
```

The format of the output depends on the callback. See [*DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback). If you use *ansible.builtin.default* callback set ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_RESULT_FORMAT=yaml

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_RESULT_FORMAT=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml

  ...
ok: [test_11] => 
    msg: |-
        file1 from /tmp/dir1:
          31,32d30
          < User1:*:1002:1004:My User1:/home/User1:/bin/sh
          < MyUser1:*:1003:1005:My User1:/home/MyUser1:/bin/sh
        file1 from /tmp/dir2:
          31,32d30
          < User1:*:1002:1004:My User1:/home/User1:/bin/sh
          < MyUser1:*:1003:1005:My User1:/home/MyUser1:/bin/sh
        file2 from /tmp/dir1:
          33,34d32
          < alice:*:1004:1006:Alice:/home/alice:/bin/sh
          < bob:*:1005:1007:Bob:/home/bob:/bin/sh
        file2 from /tmp/dir2:
          33,34d32
          < alice:*:1004:1006:Alice:/home/alice:/bin/sh
          < bob:*:1005:1007:Bob:/home/bob:/bin/sh
ok: [test_13] => 
    msg: ""
```

See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t callback ansible.builtin.default
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for the help man.
However the msg module output is not to my liking
I rather would prefer format similar like given in Q inside output section

can it be achieved? I mean I can afford any other module.

Comment: I am accepting the answer though

Comment: I meant output with proper newline characters, currently I am getting this
```ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "file2 from $PWD/dir1: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < abc123\n  < def456\n  ---\n  > abc101\n  > def111\nfile2 from $PWD/dir2: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < abc123\n  < def456\n  ---\n  > abc101\n  > def111\nfile1 from $PWD/dir1: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < 123abc\n  < 456def\n  ---\n  > 101abc\n  > 111def\nfile1 from $PWD/dir2: \n  1,2c1,2\n  < 123abc\n  < 456def\n  ---\n  > 101abc\n  > 111def\n"
}```

Comment: It's difficult to see the formatting in the comment. Wouldn't you mind putting it into the question? Just click the edit button in your question. Should I do it for you?

Comment: I have added the output in Q section now. A report-like output is prefered rather default from diff like this

Comment: The format of the output depends on the callback. I updated the answer.